# how to tell if .selection.find found anything in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, find

I can use this code to find a sentence in a user-specified word file and insert the text after that sentence. The problem is if the expected sentence is not existing in the word file, the text will be inserted in the beginning of the word file. What I need is, if the expected sentence is not found, go to error handler. How to modify the code?

[updated]The below code works:

```
Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object
Dim FullName As String: FullName = Sheet5.Cells(7, 5).Value

Set WordApp = New Word.Application

With WordApp
    .Visible = True

    Set WordDoc = .Documents.Open(FullName)

    .ActiveDocument.Select
    With .Selection
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .Text = "There is one electric heater."
            .Execute
        End With
        If .Find.Found Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        .TypeParagraph
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .MoveEnd wdLine, 1
        Sheet3.Range("G2").Copy
        .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        Sheet2.Range("A1", "B10").Copy
        .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        Else
        MsgBox "No electric heater reference found.", vbExclamation
        End If
    End With
    .Activate
End With
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the code is used repeatedly? And that it probably worked a "first time"... Unfortunately, you don't provide the full code nor explain how you "updated" the code that previously worked. Without that information no one can help you. If you consult the information in the site's [help] about asking questions you'll see that you're expected to provide a [mcve] so that people are able to help you.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks fo your comment. I fixed this issue this time. Will post more useful information when I ask a question in the future.

Comment: @CindyMeister I changed my question. Could you please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Your code still won't compile - where's the `If` that matches the `End If`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object, WordRng As Object
Dim strFlNm As String: strFlNm = Sheet5.Range("D6").Value
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With WordApp
  .Visible = True
  Set WordDoc = .Documents.Open(strFlNm)
  With WordDoc.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .MatchCase = False
      .Text = "There is one electric heater."
      .Execute
    End With
    If .Find.Found = True Then
      .InsertAfter vbCr
      .Collapse 0 ' wdCollapseEnd
      .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0 'wdAlignParagraphLeft
      Sheet3.Range("G2").Copy
      .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
      .InsertAfter vbCr
      Sheet2.Range("A1:B10").Copy
      .Collapse 0 ' wdCollapseEnd
      .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    Else
      MsgBox "No electric heater reference found", vbExclamation
    End If
  End With
  .Activate
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. The code works very well. Actually I tried adding some new code to insert `Sheet2.Range("A1","B10")` after `Sheet3.Range("G2")` in the word file. However, the new part is inserted before the `Sheet3.Range("G2")`.  (Sorry. I don't know how to post the code in the comment. Press ctrl+k will open the Chrome search box, not toggling the code )

Comment: Your updated code still put the `Sheet2.Range("A1:B10")` before `Sheet3.Range("G2")` in the word file. I fixed and put the updated code in the question. Thanks for your help.